# Karaf / OSGI + Hibernate + Hibernate Search + Mysql

Tags: hibernate, osgi, hibernate-search, apache-karaf, karaf

I think i have followed all of the examples on both Hibernate Search and Hibernate for OSGI.  I seem to have everything working and wired up, but then I can't ever get a SessionFactory, basically in my HibernateUtil,

```
sf = (SessionFactory) context.getService( sr );
```

sf is always null.  I am debugging and setting through and see SR is not null, but SF is null and have no what to debug.   Below are the details, including my features.xml:

```
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0"
        name="hdscores">

    <feature name="hibernate-search" version="${versions.hibernate-search-orm}">
        <!-- JTA -->
        <bundle dependency="true" start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.0.0</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.manager/1.0.1</bundle>
        <!-- JPA -->
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final</bundle>
        <!-- JBoss Logging and Hibernate Commons Annotations -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/${versions.jboss-logging}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/${versions.hibernate-commons-annotation}</bundle>
        <!--
        Lucene dependencies - Unfortunately, Lucene does not publish artifacts with OSGi metadata, so we are on our own.
        I tried the bundles provided by Apache ServiceMix, but they are broken. They don't contains the ServiceLoader files.
        That is correct from an OSGi point of view, but Lucene falls over without them.
        Instead falling back to Karaf's built-in wrapping functionality which also needs customizing. Plain wrapping
        does not work and additional properties (work in progress there) needs to be specified. In particular the
        export configuration.
        -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jakarta-regexp/1.4_1</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/${versions.lucene}$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.hibernate.org.apache.lucene.core&amp;Export-Package=org.apache.lucene;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene3x;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene46;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.document;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.index;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.search;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.search.payloads;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.search.similarities;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.search.spans;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.store;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.util;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.util.automaton;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.util.fst;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.util.mutable;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.util.packed;version="${versions.lucene}"</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.lucene/lucene-queryparser/${versions.lucene}$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.hibernate.org.apache.lucene.queryparser</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.lucene/lucene-queries/${versions.lucene}$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.hibernate.org.apache.lucene.queries&amp;Export-Package=org.apache.lucene.queries;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.queries.function;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.queries.mlt;version="${versions.lucene}"</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/${versions.lucene}$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.hibernate.org.apache.lucene.analyzers.common&amp;Export-Package=org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.bg;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.br;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.ca;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.charfilter;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.cjk;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.commongrams;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.compound;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.core;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.cz;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.da;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.de;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.el;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.en;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.es;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.eu;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.fa;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.fi;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.ga;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.gl;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.hi;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.hu;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.hunspell;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.hy;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.id;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.in;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.it;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.lv;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.nl;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.no;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.path;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.position;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.pt;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.query;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.reverse;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.ro;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.ru;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.shingle;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.sinks;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.sv;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.th;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.tr;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.util;version="${versions.lucene}",org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia;version="${versions.lucene}"</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.lucene/lucene-facet/${versions.lucene}$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.hibernate.org.apache.lucene.facet&amp;Export-Package=org.apache.lucene.facet.collections;version="${versions.lucene}"</bundle>
        <!-- Hibernate Search -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-search-engine/${versions.hibernate-search-orm}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm/${versions.hibernate-search-orm}</bundle>
        <!-- Test DB bundles -->
        <bundle>mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:net.sourceforge.serp/serp/1.13.1$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.hibernate.net.sourceforge.serp</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/${versions.mysql-connector}</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.3.170</bundle>

        <!-- ORM dependencies -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antlr/2.7.7_5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j/1.6.1_5</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss/jandex/1.2.0.Final</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml/classmate/0.8.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA</bundle>

        <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-core/${versions.hibernate-orm}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/${versions.hibernate-orm}</bundle>
        <!--<bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-envers/${versions.hibernate-orm}</bundle> -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/${versions.hibernate-orm}</bundle>
    </feature>


    <feature name="hdscores-test" version="${versions.features}">


        <feature>hibernate-search</feature>
        <feature>ipojo</feature>
        <feature>ipojo-command</feature>


        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.github.davidmoten/geo/${versions.geo}</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/${versions.jackson}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/${versions.jackson}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/${versions.jackson}</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:com.hdscores.bundles/common.rest/${versions.common.rest}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.hdscores.bundles/inspection.persistence.production/${versions.inspection.persistence.production}</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:com.hdscores.bundles/commands.test/${versions.commands.test}</bundle>

    </feature>
```

Then my HibernateUtil class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private SessionFactory sf;

    public Session getSession() {
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

     public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if ( sf == null ) {
            Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(HibernateUtil.class);
            // Could get this by wiring up OsgiTestBundleActivator as well.
            BundleContext context = thisBundle.getBundleContext();
            ServiceReference sr = context.getServiceReference( SessionFactory.class.getName() );
            sf = (SessionFactory) context.getService( sr );
        }
        return sf;
    }

}
```

and my hiberate.cfg.xml:

```
 <session-factory>

      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/hdscores</property> -->

      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hdscores</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">----</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">----</property>



      <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/var/hdscores/indexes</property>
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use">false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.search.lucene_version">${versions.lucene}</property>

      <!-- <property name="hibernate.search.jmx_enabled">true</property> -->

      <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>

      <!-- <property name="show_sql">true</property> -->

      <mapping class="com.hdscores.inspection.persistence.production.InspectionEntity"/>
      <mapping class="com.hdscores.inspection.persistence.production.ViolationEntity"/>
      <mapping class="com.hdscores.inspection.persistence.production.ComplianceEntity"/>
      <mapping class="com.hdscores.inspection.persistence.production.TemperatureEntity"/>
      <mapping class="com.hdscores.inspection.persistence.production.EstablishmentEntity"/>
      <mapping class="com.hdscores.inspection.persistence.production.StagingLogEntity"/>



      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->

<!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And finally the karaf log when i try to run a test command:

```
2015-02-17 23:44:38,874 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Version                          | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-02-17 23:44:38,889 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Version                          | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2015-02-17 23:44:38,895 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Environment                      | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-02-17 23:44:38,898 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Environment                      | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-02-17 23:44:39,932 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Configuration                    | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2015-02-17 23:44:39,933 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Configuration                    | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2015-02-17 23:44:40,063 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Configuration                    | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2015-02-17 23:44:40,306 | WARN  | l for user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2015-02-17 23:44:40,318 | INFO  | l for user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hdscores]
2015-02-17 23:44:40,319 | INFO  | l for user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
2015-02-17 23:44:40,319 | INFO  | l for user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
2015-02-17 23:44:40,322 | INFO  | l for user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2015-02-17 23:44:40,806 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Dialect                          | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2015-02-17 23:44:42,127 | INFO  | l for user karaf | TransactionFactoryInitiator      | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2015-02-17 23:44:42,137 | INFO  | l for user karaf | ASTQueryTranslatorFactory        | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-02-17 23:44:42,322 | INFO  | l for user karaf | Version                          | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.0.1.Final
2015-02-17 23:44:44,448 | WARN  | l for user karaf | SessionFactoryImpl               | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000008: JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()
2015-02-17 23:44:45,081 | INFO  | l for user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 230 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hdscores]
2015-02-17 23:44:50,593 | ERROR | l for user karaf | ShellUtil                        | 25 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.3 | Exception caught while executing command
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these errors happen when not importing the proper Hibernate packages on the manifest. If you use hibernate import the following at least:

```
org.hibernate;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.cfg;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.service;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.proxy;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.mapping;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.annotations;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.envers.*;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.boot.registry;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.internal.util;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.criterion;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.dialect;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.dialect.function;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.exception;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.jdbc;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.property;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.type;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.osgi;version=${hibernate.core.version},
```